# Within a Script, how to test if using Corretto or Oracle JRE?

Tags: java, corretto

Lets say a program executes which dynamically builds a script (shell script on Linux or bat file on windows) which obtains reference to the Java Home via the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

It is important to ensure that JAVA_HOME references Corretto and not Oracle JRE?

Is there a direct way to determine if the JRE being referenced is Corretto or Oracle?

One possible way would be to run "java -version" capture the output and parse for "Corretto" or "Oracle" but wasn't sure if there is some other means for checking.

I just noticed there is a "release" item under the JAVA_HOME which could work if parsed for "Amazon.com Inc." but not certain if this file is a standard and would expect to be available in future versions.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? System.getProperty("java.vendor")

Comment: That may work, thanks.